# jQuery DIV full height of document body DYNAMICALLY

Tags: jquery, dom, height, element

Man I have looked at literally dozens of what seem to be identical questions...and none of those solutions is working.

My code isn't very complicated--I'm creating a DIV on-the-fly, associating an id with it, giving it a height and then adding the DOM element:

`S = document.createElement('div');
S.setAttribute('id','viewbg');
var pageHeight = getVpHeight();
$('#viewbg').css('height', pageHeight + 'px');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(S);`

When I put an alert(pageHeight) after the getVpHeight function call, it has the correct height (full document height, not just window size) but the div ALWAYS defaults to the original css styles defined in the stylesheet, ignoring any new number.

I've tried changing the height after the DOM is created but it does the same thing. I also tried the jQuery (window).resize function and that did nothing.

Am I missing something? Is there a jQuery/CSS wizard who can spot what is going on?

Comment: In fact, even after removing all references to #viewbg in the original stylesheet, and manually creating them with the creation of the div (background color, position, etc.), it displays nothing at all. Bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call the css() method on an empty selector (the element you are selecting doesn't exist in the DOM yet.

You could do:

```
var pageHeight = $(window).height();
 S = $('<div>', {id:'viewbg',height: pageHeight} );
$('body').append(S);
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/urWJS/

Comment: console.log is the only thing I haven't seen before--what is this? It seems to me (since none of the methods mentioned here work either) that this really might be a DOM precedence issue and that the overriding height number always comes from the default stylesheet.

Comment: console.log is just a way to output data to the firebug console, it does nothing (i deleted it!) but causes problems if you don't have firebug...anyway i edited the fiddle adding an heigth property in the css and it's overidden from what i set in code...look here http://jsfiddle.net/urWJS/3/ (if you remove the heigth attribute from javascript heigth is 50px only)

Comment: Yeah it LOOKS like it should all work...but my guess is the fiddle UI isn't showing what the DIV's behavior is in a full page. It fills the window nicely (even setting the height before the DOM element is created!) but as soon as you scroll down it ends. Is t here any mechanism to "refresh" or reset a DIV's style settings prior to its creation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could simply be that your stylesheet is overriding the styles you're adding.

Have you tried:

```
 $('#viewbg').css('height', pageHeight + 'px !important');
```

**UPDATE**

As Nicola has pointed out, you're trying to grab an element from the page that's not yet been inserted and thus you can't style it in the way you'd like.

In addition to Nicola's answer I'll also point out that you can style the element by using jQuery to select it from the variable it exists in as follows:

```
$(S).css('height', pageHeight + 'px');
```

Full source:

```
S = document.createElement('div');
S.setAttribute('id','viewbg');
var pageHeight = $(window).height();
$(S).css('height', pageHeight + 'px');
$('body').append(S);
```

**UPDATE 2**

To get the height of the document rather than the height of the window you can use:

```
var pageHeight = $(document).height();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/urWJS/2/

Comment: i think that the problem is that $('#viewbg') is not in the DOM and so you can't select it.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, I missed that bit. I've updated my answer with another solution slightly different to your own.

Comment: I like some of the shorthand jquery stuff, and the fact that I was trying to change the height of an element that didn't yet exist in the DOM was important...but the net result is the same in all of the above methods. The new DIV's height is only the height of the window, NOT the full document height.

Comment: Could it be that the creation of an iframe would interfere with what the browser understands as 100% height? I'm not creating an iframe inside the div in question but in a second, overlapping one. Seems like a long shot but I can't figure out any other reason why this isn't working.

Comment: See UPDATE 2. This may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, well, well. It didn't work so as an experiment I opened up Safari instead of FF 5 and it works in Safari. So this is a FF issue?? Originally I had been using more detailed cross-browser code to get the document height but had used the simpler jquery `$(document).height()` here...which I'd assumed would cover all the bases?

Comment: I haven't tested this in FF5 however I would imagine it to work. Are you sure it's not showing a cached version?

Comment: I shift-refresh often but I cleared the cache and tried again. Same story; fills the window, not the entire document. Not sure what else to try. The easy workaround is just to specify a massive height in the original stylesheet...like 300% but it makes the scrollbar jump on click. Thanks for your excellent help on this.